# MySQL Workbench - All diagrams in EER Model update when working in single diagram

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, eer-model

I've created an EER Model for a project and I have a couple diagrams inside the model.
My problem is that I have tables with the same name in all the diagrams and when I update one table, all with the same name suffer the same alterations.

How can I avoid this behavior and have a diagram independant from the others?

Comment: Do you say that you have several schemas each with a table that has the same name as in other schemas? Or is that you have just one schema with a table that you place on several diagrams?

Comment: I have just one schema with the same table (copy + paste) in other diagrams

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MySQL Workbench it is possible to place the same table on more than one diagram. All these "instances" (we call them **figures**) represent the same db object. Hence changing that table it will appear changed on all diagrams. It's the same object after all.

Comment: thank you @Mike, so there's no way to create exceptions while updating tables in the same schema in one particular diagram?

Comment: Not at the moment. You could file a feature request (http://bugs.mysql.com) so we can plan for that.